# Rollback problems with new Neo4jTransactionManager

Tags: java, neo4j, transactions, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using **Spring-data-neo4j 4.2.0.RC1** and I have **problems with the new Neo4jTransactionManager** class.

I have **problems with transaction rollbacks**. **Exceptions are thrown from Neo4jTransactionManager class that are overriding application exceptions on rollbacks**.

I have seen 2 different problems (Neo4jTransactionManager.doRollback() around line 275):

- NullPointerException (tx is null)
- Another exception thrown on tx.rollback() that is overriding application exception

**I have patched the method**:

- with a if(tx != null)...
- and a catch around tx.rollback() to hide all exceptions

**and now my transactions are rollbacking correctly.**

I don't know if there are **bugs** around this class **or if I configured my application incorrectly**.

Comment: This is a new feature and a significant change. I'll check with the author regarding expected usage. In the meantime, let's treat it as a bug. Are you able to forward a sample with failing test case, or other reproduction of the problem to jasper@graphaware.com?

Comment: Could you pls also verify that same behavior is exhibited with 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to isolate the problem in a test case. Could you provide me a maven repository where I can find latest 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ? I'm using http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot but I can only see old 4.2.0 snapshots.

Comment: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot is the correct one

Comment: But I don't understand, why is the latest snapshot from April 16, which is 3 months older than 4.2.0.M1 ?

Comment: I took a look - I see recent builds in there.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.. I was looking at folder's creation date. I will try with the latest snapshots. Thanks

Comment: Issue tracked here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-952